# Editing in-place feature in ASP.NET webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I need to add a feature that allows users to create surveys. How can I create it in such a way that it was be edited "in place". The idea is that I needn't create multiple pages to view survey and edit survey. There will be a submit button on the page to update in in database. How can it be done in such a way that there is just one post. (There are same number of options for all questions)

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8400153/440030 :)

Comment: So is it classic WebForms or ASP.NET MVC that you are working on?

Comment: @neutrino, OK, removing the `asp.net-mvc` tag from your question then as it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is more related to javascript or other client technology.
If you're using jquery, there are many plugins available that does what you want just search for "edit in place", i found [JEditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) and [jquery-in-place-editor](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-in-place-editor/)