# jQuery to save to database in ASP.NET webforms

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I am not familiar with javascript. The answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400639/creating-add-survey-feature-in-asp-net-webforms) question made me realize the power of jQuery. But unfortunately, I didn't still understand how it works when results should be stored in database (like jEditable). Can someone please explain this or point me to an easy to understand reference for beginners.

Comment: Have a Google for 'Saving to a database using AJAX'.

Comment: @neutrino from the other question you asked what you want is minimize the posts you do to edit/create records. So basically, what you need to do is edit your data(or viewmodel), or the fields in your form using javascript, before posting it to the server. Check [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2008/11/20/building-a-neat-edit-in-place-behavior.aspx) you can find source code with a demo to download!

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is your question? jEditable is a jquery plugin for enabling edit in place functionality. By itself it cannot save to the db.  However you'll still need some sort of server side code and data access layer to persist the changes to the db. Classic ado/net or Entity framework an be used to persist the chnages to the underlying database.